# How do you remove the word "Figure" when referencing a figure?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

So I have my figures labeled as "Figure section.figurenumber", meaning each caption starts with, say, "Figure 1.1", "Figure 1.2", and "Figure 2.1" if in sections 1 and 2, respectively.  I've accomplished this by putting the following in my preamble:

> \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure \arabic{section}.\arabic{subfigure}}

The reason I'm using subfigures is to be able to have figures side-by-side on a page.  Anyway, when I reference these figures in the actual text, like, "please see figures \ref{label1} and \ref{label2}," the actual output is "please see figures Figure 1.1 and Figure 1.2".

How can I maintain the word "Figure" in my caption but suppress it when referencing the figure in the text?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx, caption}
\usepackage{float} %Needed for the [H] after \begin{figure}.  [H] stands for "Here", 
i.e., the figures appear in the PDF in the same location as in the TeX code.

\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure \arabic{section}.\arabic{subfigure}}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{center} \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{stars.jpeg} \end{center}
    \caption{A picture of the past.}
    \label{fig:stars}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~~~
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{center} \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{monkeys.jpeg} \end{center}
    \caption{Humans not too long ago.}
    \label{fig:primates}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~~~
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.42\textwidth}
    \begin{center} \includegraphics[scale=0.16]{lion.jpeg} \end{center}
    \caption{Not today Satan.}
    \label{fig:predator}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~~~
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.42\textwidth}
    \begin{center} \includegraphics[scale=0.16]{blueberry.jpeg} \end{center}
    \caption{Is this a blueberry-topped cupcake, or just a cup of blueberries?.}
    \label{fig:enigma}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~~~
\end{figure}
As we can see in figures \subref{fig:stars} and \subref{fig:enigma}, I'm not very good at making a minimal working example.
\end{document}
```

And this gives the output:

[image]

Comment: AFAIK the `thexxx` command should never feature the name of the float they refer to.

Comment: @Moriambar Sorry, but what is 'thexxx' command?

Comment: `\thefigure` `\thetable` `\thechapter` `\thesection` ... `xxx` was just a placeholder. Nevertheless they should only indicate how to render the proper counter number, not contain the "Figure" or something like that.

Comment: @Moriambar Ok, so is there another way to add the word "Figure" into the caption?

Comment: `\caption` should do this ... for more, you should provide MWE.

Comment: @Zarko \caption does not automatically do it.  At least not for me when using subfigures.

Comment: show the code, that we can see what is going on. if this is case, then you have something exceptional or we don't understand each other. so, again, provide MWE.

Comment: Note that if you want to have figures side by side without using subfigures (which is quite unnatural), you  simply load the `floatrow` package and its eponymous environment.

Comment: why would you want to number your subfigures as section.subfigure without mentioning the figure number? isn't that going to be confusing for the reader. It is very hard for anyone to suggest how to fix your code if you do not show it. Please show a small complete document that shows the subfigure definition you are using

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There is no figure number.  In section 1, I have one figure, and inside of it 3 subfigures (so in the PDF, you basically just see 3 figures -- I use subfigure just to have figures side-by-side).  The figures are then labeled in the paper like: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3.  That's not confusing.  There's no mention of the "figure" number because there's no real "figure" in the paper.  Just subfigures.

Comment: To everyone: I'm trying to produce a MWE.

Comment: there is no reason to use subfigure to affect the _position_ it is just about numbering.

Comment: @Zarko Before I read the currently posted answer, I wanted to notify you I put together a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments it seems that you do not what subfigures at all but something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\section{Zzzzzz}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.33\linewidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
     \caption{Zzzzz\label{zza}}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.33\linewidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
     \caption{Zzzzz zzz\label{zzb}}  
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.33\linewidth}
        \centering
     \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
     \caption{Zzzzz zzzzzz\label{zzc}}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

See figures \ref{zza} to \ref{zzc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want, and you posted this 2 minutes before I finished painstakingly putting together a minimal working example.  Thanks for your answer.  I'll read through it now.

Comment: @user46944 ah well I've done this before:-)

Comment: So you basically used minipage, and TeX put in the word "Figure" automatically.  Do you know if your solution will work across multiple pages?  For example, if I have so many figures that they span multiple pages.  I think I had a problem with this in the past.

Comment: @user46944 the `figure` environment never spans more than one page.

Comment: So do I just create a new figure environment for the next page?  Will the numbering carry on as expected?

Comment: @user46944 the insertion of the  `Figure` is just the standard latex `\caption` command, unrelated to the minipages.

Comment: @user46944 yes of course

Comment: Last question.  In my code, the label appears to be "Fig 1.1" instead of "Figure 1.1".  I'm not opposed to this, but do you have any idea why it would select "Fig" for me?  I thought I implemented your suggestion exactly like you did.